# Jackson - Transform field value on serialization

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

In a Spring Boot applicaion with AngularJS frontend, a "Pin" field value has to be blackened on serialization, i.e., if the Pin field value is null in the POJO, the according JSON field has to remain blank; if the field value contains data, it has to be replaced with a "***" string.

Does Jackson provide a feature to get this done?

Comment: You will need customer serializer for that have a look here - http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it easily like following without any Custom Serializer

```
public class Pojo {
    @JsonIgnore
    private String pin;

    @JsonProperty("pin")
    public String getPin() {
        if(pin == null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return "***";
        }
    }

    @JsonProperty("pin")
    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPinValue() {
        return pin;
    }

}
```

You can use `Pojo.getPinValue()` to get the exact value.

Comment: While the approach posted by Anton Belev would be a cleaner one regarding architecture, I prefer this one since it is a quick and small solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try the following example.

```
public class Card {
    public int id;
    public String pin;
}

public class CardSerializer extends StdSerializer<Card> {

    public CardSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public CardSerializer(Class<Card> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Card value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
        jgen.writeStringField("pin", "****");
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then you need to register your customer serializer with the `ObjectMapper`

```
Card card = new Card(1, "12345");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Card.class, new CardSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(card);
```

There are some improvements you can do here like registering the serializer directly on the class, but you can read more about it here Section 4 - http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: This is the proper way to do it.